# Retrieve last entry via ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, importhtml

Looking for help pulling specific cells from a web site into a Google Spreadsheet. I want to pull ["**last**" price from this page](http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/markets/indexes.asp) but only a few specific ones. Such as Dow, Nasdaq 100, S&P 500, S&P 400 Mid Cap and Russell 2000. I tried using `ImportXML`and managed to import the whole table but can't seem to figure out how to pull just those cells. I also want to be able to do each cell individually so I can move and adjust the spreadsheet to my liking.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
=index(importhtml("http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/markets/indexes.asp","Table"),5,4)
```

for the NASDAQ 100 Index and adjust the `5` to suit for others.

Answer (score 1):

The following setup will return the last price for `NASDAQ 100 Index (NASDAQ Calculation)`

A1: `http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/markets/indexes.asp`
A2: `=//tr[contains(.,'NASDAQ 100 Index (NASDAQ Calculation)')]/td[4]`
A3 Formula: `=IMPORTXML(A1,A2)`
A3 Result: `4,512.54`